# XamarinForm CarouselPage - UWP Slideshow

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

Im trying to develop simple intro in my Xamarin app [For UWP], similar to slideshow with navigation dots ( https://github.com/chrisriesgo/xamarin-forms-carouselview - i think its too complicated, and its not for windows platform. Another example but its not work : https://gist.github.com/adamped/9367c64e64e12e063508309f35a9d6eb#file-carouselview-indicators) . Is there any easy way to add dots to Xamarin.Form.CarouselPage ?

Slideshow.cs:

```
public SlideShow()
        {
            Children.Add(new SimpleContentPage1());
            Children.Add(new SimpleContentPage2());
            Children.Add(new SimpleContentPage3());
        }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
var slidePage = new SlideShow();
        MainPage = slidePage;
```

Each ContentPage has some image / label / custom control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to add dots to Xamarin.Form.CarouselPage?

Sure, let's see how Xamarin implements this control:

For UWP, Xamarin uses the Renderer under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT` namespace, see [CarouselPageRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/CarouselPageRenderer.cs#L17)

```
public class CarouselPageRenderer : FlipView, IVisualElementRenderer
```

It actually inherits from [`FlipView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx) control.

So we can create a style which target type is `FlipView` and add an item indicator.

1. Create a control for indicator([LINK](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/CarouselPage/UWP/Controls/FlipViewIndicator.cs)):

   ```
   public sealed class FlipViewIndicator : ListBox
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FlipViewIndicator"/> class.
   /// </summary>
   public FlipViewIndicator()
   {
       this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(FlipViewIndicator);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets or sets the flip view.
   /// </summary>
   public FlipView FlipView
   {
       get { return (FlipView)GetValue(FlipViewProperty); }
       set { SetValue(FlipViewProperty, value); }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Identifies the <see cref="FlipView"/> dependency property
   /// </summary>
   public static readonly DependencyProperty FlipViewProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("FlipView", typeof(FlipView), typeof(FlipViewIndicator), new PropertyMetadata(null, (depobj, args) =>
       {
           FlipViewIndicator fvi = (FlipViewIndicator)depobj;
           FlipView fv = (FlipView)args.NewValue;

           // this is a special case where ItemsSource is set in code
           // and the associated FlipView's ItemsSource may not be available yet
           // if it isn't available, let's listen for SelectionChanged 
           fv.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
           {
               fvi.ItemsSource = fv.Items;
           };

           fvi.ItemsSource = fv.Items;

           // create the element binding source
           Binding eb = new Binding();
           eb.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
           eb.Source = fv;
           eb.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem");

           // set the element binding to change selection when the FlipView changes
           fvi.SetBinding(FlipViewIndicator.SelectedItemProperty, eb);
       }));
   ```

   }
2. Theme([themes\Generic.xaml](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/CarouselPage/UWP/themes/Generic.xaml)):

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorUnselectedThemeBrush">Gray</SolidColorBrush>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush">#FFFFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
       </ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorUnselectedThemeBrush">Gray</SolidColorBrush>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush">#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
       </ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorUnselectedThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorButtonFaceColor}" />
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="FlipViewIndicatorItem">
       <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,10,4"/>
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                   <Grid>
                       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                           <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                               <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                               <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorItem">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush}"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                               </VisualState>
                               <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorItem">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush}"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                               </VisualState>
                               <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorItem">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource FlipViewIndicatorSelectedThemeBrush}"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                               </VisualState>
                           </VisualStateGroup>
                       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                       <Ellipse x:Name="PART_FlipViewIndicatorItem" 
                                  Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{ThemeResource FlipViewIndicatorUnselectedThemeBrush}" 
                                  Margin="0,5,5,0" />
                   </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>

   <Style TargetType="local:FlipViewIndicator">
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,0,0" />
       <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource FlipViewIndicatorItem}" />
       <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
       <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
       <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
       <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                   <Border x:Name="PART_FlipViewIndicatorLayoutRoot" 
                           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                           BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                           <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                               <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                               <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorLayoutRoot">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorLayoutRoot">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                               </VisualState>
                           </VisualStateGroup>
                           <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                               <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                   <Storyboard>
                                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FlipViewIndicatorLayoutRoot">
                                           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                   </Storyboard>
                               </VisualState>
                               <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                           </VisualStateGroup>
                       </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                       <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
                                     HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" 
                                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                     IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" 
                                     IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" 
                                     Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" 
                                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                     VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                     ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                           <ItemsPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                       </ScrollViewer>
                   </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
   ```
3. Modify [the default template of FlipView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299124.aspx), use the above control([LINK](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/CarouselPage/UWP/App.xaml)):

   ```
   <Application
   x:Class="CarouselPageNavigation.UWP.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:CarouselPageNavigation.UWP"
   xmlns:control="using:CarouselPageNavigation.UWP.Controls"
   RequestedTheme="Light">
   <Application.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="FlipView">
           <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                       <Grid>
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
           BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                               <Grid.Resources>
                                   <!--Omitted-->
                               </Grid.Resources>
                           </Grid>
                           <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                               <control:FlipViewIndicator FlipView="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       Margin="5"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </Grid>

                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```

**Please see my demo in [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/CarouselPage/UWP)**

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]